# smtplib sends blank message if the message contains certain characters

Tags: python, email, smtplib

My current script allows me to send emails fine, but there are just some characters it doesn't like, particularly `':'` in this sample.

```
import smtplib, sys

mensaje = sys.argv[1]
def mailto(toaddrs, msg):
    fromaddr = 'myemailblabla'

    username = 'thisismyemail'
    password = '122344'

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server.quit()

mailto('test@gmail.com', mensaje)
```

If I write a sample message such as, let's say `"Hi there\n how are you?"` it works fine, but let's say I try to send a url `http://www.neopets.com`, the email is sent blank. I believe the `':'` causes this issue, so I tried escaping it, but nothing.

Comment: The reason the colon is problematic is that it makes the line similar to a `Headername: value` email header, so it gets hidden by many receiving clients as an unknown and probably unimportant header. Some email software will attempt to move clearly non-header text to the body, but you really can't depend on this behavior. The correct solution is to send a properly formatted message in the first place.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that `smtplib` is not putting a blank line between the message header and the message body as shown by in the "Show Original" form of my test:

```
Return-Path: <me@gmail.com>
Received: **REDACTED**
        Fri, 03 Aug 2012 06:56:20 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <501bd884.850c320b@mx.google.com>
Date: Fri, 03 Aug 2012 06:56:20 -0700 (PDT)
From: me@gmail.com
http: //www.example.com
```

Although this is a legal mail header, Mail Transfer Agents and Mail User Agents should ignore apparent header fields they don't understand. And because the RFC822 header continues until the first blank line and `http:` looks like a header line, it is parsed as if it were a header. If given a newline:

```
mensaje = '\nhttp://www.example.com'
```

Then it works as expected. Although email technically only needs the "envelope" as provided by `smtplib` the contents of the mail should be more complete if you expect your recipients (and their mailers) to treat the message nicely, you should probably use the [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) module to generate the body.

**added**

Based on the doctest in `smtplib.py` it looks as if this is an intentional feature allowing the caller of `sendmail()` to append to the header:

```
     >>> msg = '''\\
     ... From: Me@my.org
     ... Subject: testin'...
     ...
     ... This is a test '''
     >>> s.sendmail("me@my.org", tolist, msg)
```

Where the `From:` and `Subject:` lines are part of the "nice" headers I mentioned above.

Comment: Reformatting the input you give it is not at all a responsibility or mandate of `smtplib`. The problem is that *you* are not properly putting an empty line between headers and body.

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution is to use the Python `email` library to create a valid message, instead of painstakingly learning (or wildly guessing at random) how to construct a valid MIME message structure by joining together pieces of text.

Some email servers will (more or less helpfully) accept invalid messages, but don't be surprised if something stops working when the server-side software is updated or a random recipient runs software which is stricter about what it will accept or display. For robustness, reliability, and predictability, do not try to send invalid messages.

A trivial RFC822 message which contains only ASCII can easily be created with

```
"From: {0}\nTo: {1}\nSubject: {2}\n\n{3}".format(
    fromaddr, toaddr,
    "Hello, I am the exiled prince of Ubandingba",
    "http://clickme.example.net/scam/")
```

but as soon as you need anything with other character sets, lines longer than some 80 characters, content types other than plain text, or in general anything more advanced than plain text English-language email as it was in 1990, the code should look something like

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg["from"] = fromaddr
msg["to"] = toaddr
msg["subject"] = "You have been nominated for the Nobel prize"
msg.set_content("http://scam.example.org/clickme")
```

which is admittedly slightly more verbose, but also infinitely more versatile, robust, and extensible.

This uses the `EmailMessage` API which was officially introduced in Python 3.6. New code should probably target this platform rather than the legacy `email.Message` module from earlier versions (or the `MIMEMultipart`, `MIMEText` etc components), although most online code examples you can find will be for the older Python library. See [the Python `email` examples documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) for some quick examples.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is about the colon but it's about `http://` starting the message.

```
mailto('test@gmail.com', 'http://www.url.com')
mailto('test@gmail.com', 'http://www.url.com that is a url')
mailto('test@gmail.com', ' http://www.url.com')
```

all fail, but:

```
mailto('test@gmail.com', 'Here is a url http://www.url.com')
```

comes through fine.

Comment: Most email clients will interpret strings which start with a sequence of alphabetics followed by a colon as a header they don't understand, and hide it. If the string doesn't have a colon at the end of the first token, some clients will infer that it must be part of the body, but others will simply hide that too, and/or complain that the message is invalid. Both variations are technically invalid. The bottom line is, don't try to assemble email messages by pasting strings together unless you know exactly what you are doing (in which case you will amost certainly use the `email` module anyway).