# Python sending email without content

Tags: python, email, smtp

SMTP send empty message, I'm reading text from a file, then I want to send it.
File looks like:

```
Date           Time    :          Text

2019-01-18 12:56:00,022: 'something i want to say'
```

Tried read(), readline(), readlines().

```
import smtplib

A = []
fh = open("text.txt", "r")
content = fh.read()
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('my_email','my_passowrd')
mail.sendmail('my_email','my_email',content)

mail.close()
```

It sends email, but it's empty.

Comment: Are you sure that `text.txt` file is not empty?

Comment: It's not. It's full with "2019-01-18 12:56:00,022: 'something i want to say'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [smtplib sends blank message if the message contain certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796664/smtplib-sends-blank-message-if-the-message-contain-certain-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer given to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26876987/7883192) might be the solution.

The answer mentions that content should be started with a new line. If that's not the case the content becomes part of the message header rather than the message body.

And one more point I noticed is in the documentation of [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail), it is given that from_address and to_address should follow the [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.html) format. Once you check whether you are correctly following that format or not.

So I don't know if this would work or not, try changing "from_address" to  "<"+"from_address"+">".