# Why are the subject and content empty when using python to send Email?

Tags: python, email

I tried to run the following python script (copied from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm) on a remote server to send an Email. I successfully received the Email in my mailbox, but unfortunately the content is always empty. Another problem is, if I slightly change the message within """From: xxx """, say delete this part `From: sender Name`, then I could even receive the empty Email. What is the magic going on inside message line """xxx"""?

```
import smtplib
def send_Email2():

    sender = 'username@company.com'
    receivers = "receivername@company.com"    
    message = """From: Sender Name  <username@company.com>
         To: Receiver Name <receivername@company.com>
         Subject: SMTP e-mail test

         This is a test e-mail message.
         """

   try:
       smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('1xx.128.2.xxx',25)
       smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)  
       print "Successfully sent email"
   except SMTPException:
       print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796664/smtplib-sends-blank-message-if-the-message-contain-certain-characters) helps

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried like below:

```
message['Subject'] = 'SMTP e-mail test'
message['From'] = 'username@company.com'
message['To'] = 'receivername@company.com'
```

Comment: It is the right direction. I ended up using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments-with-python.