# getting a blank email

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I have quickly written below code to send data being sent to REST remote server for debuging but I am receiving blank email. now sure what is going wrong . in the terminal body dict text or json converted text is getting printed but  getting nothing  in email.

```
# For testing
def sendMail(usr, pwd, to, body):
    """ just for testing to send error via email
    """
    fromaddr = usr
    toaddr = to
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Data add request"
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(usr, pwd)
        msg.attach(body)
        r = json.dumps(body)
        loaded_r = json.loads(r)
        print "json: ", str(loaded_r)
        server.sendmail("error-report@do_not_reply.com", to,  str(loaded_r))
    except Exception, err:
        print 'Error sending email: ', err
    finally:
        server.quit()
```

I tried sending `server.sendmail("error-report@do_not_reply.com", to,  body)` but that too sends blank email without subject. what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: is this doesn't solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796664/smtplib-sends-blank-message-if-the-message-contain-certain-characters

Comment: Right now would probably be a very good moment to start thinking about migrating your code to the currently recommended and supported version of the Python language, which is version 3. Personally I have atterpted for the last two years to migrate all the code I maintain to Python 3 whenever there was a need to do maintenance, and I'm still far from done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you pass as the third argument to `sendmail` needs to be a valid, properly formatted RFC822 message. A JSON file is, by definition, not a valid email message.

```
def sendMail(usr, pwd, to, body):
    msg = MIMEText(body)
    msg['From'] = usr
    msg['To'] = to
    msg['Subject'] = "Data add request"
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(usr, pwd)
        server.send_message(msg, "error-report@do_not_reply.com", [to])
    except Exception, err:
        print 'Error sending email: ', err
    finally:
        server.quit()
```

I switched to `send_message` here because it takes care of the minor mundane detail of converting the `email.Message` object to a string object again before calling `sendmail`.

It's not clear if you expect the body to be a text part displaying the contents of the string `body`, or a JSON attachment containing `body` as JSON, or perhaps both.

If you only need one body part, making the message multipart is obviously unnecessary. If you want multiple parts, then each of them should be a separate `MIMEText` or some other MIME container type which you can `msg.attach()` to a top-level `MIMEMultipart`.

Comment: There is a new and improved API in Python 3.6+ which uses `EmailMessage` instead of `Message`. Now code should probably use this API instead, and probably not call the various MIME constructors directly, which was the norm with the older version of the library. In very brief, `msg = email.message.EmailMessage(policy=default)` and then call its methods to add body contents and/or attachments.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's the message : you should put for message

```
text = loaded_r.as_string()
```

And then you can send the mail .

```
server.sendmail("error-report@do_not_reply.com", to,  text)
```